# play framework Localized routes

Tags: localization, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play 2.1.1 and java. My issue is how to route and create a non Latin url`s in order to improve the SEO  of the site

I followed these links for information and examples :

- [Localized routes](http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/11/playframework-routes-part-2-advanced/)
- [Internationalisation and localisation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/guide12)

I tried to  use the route engine like that :

```
GET     /               controllers.Application.פנסיה()
```

Application.class

```
public static Result פנסיה() {
 return ok(פנסיה.render(userForm));
```

}

Template :

```
פנסיה.scala.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up things: `controllers.Application.פנסיה()` is the target action **not** the route. I think that will be not a problem if you'll use latin chars (preferable English words) for the action names.

to make routes (so displayed URLs) non latin you need to unfortunately write them as a UTF-8 set of codes, so instead of :

```
GET /פנסיה   controller.Application.pension()
```

You need to place there something like:

```
GET /%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94 controller.Application.pension()
```

(note: this is situation confirmed in Play `2.0.x`, I don't know if there is any change in this topic in `2.1.x`)

Comment: hi , i added  this rout
 GET /%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94 controller.Application.pension()

and template
 %D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94.scala.html 

and now im getting  Compilation error[Invalid template name [%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94.scala.html]
]

i can understand that he cant find the page ...

Comment: If you don't want to consider where you made mistake(s) I can't help you.... you mixed up things totally...

Comment: ok let me try to explain  my self again 

this line   "GET /%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94   controller.Application.pension()" 
  will go to the  pension method and then i can do logic and create a new page with  this name %D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94  
 
that's correct ???

obviously  not   cus im getting this error now 
"object Application is not a member of package controller"

im missing something completely , can you help me under stand were im wrong
thanks

Comment: i took a step and read the the tutorial     again thanks for the support